# Nested resources and pretty urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, friendly-url

I have 2 models:

1. Sport
2. Competition

In my routes.rb I would normally do

```
resources :sports, :only => [:index, :show] do
  resources :competitions, , :only => [:index, :show]
end
```

This gives me urls like `/sports/1/competitions/4`

But what I want is **NOT** `:controller/:id`, but directly the `:name` as path, like so `/soccer/euro2012`

I can get the first part by doing this:

```
match "/:sports_name" => "sports#show", :as => :sport
```

And in my controller:

```
def show
  @sport = Sport.find_by_name(params[:sports_name])
end
```

But that's about it. I have no idea how to get the nested resource, or if I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Lets first make the nested resources, if you really need them, and then take care of the pretty urls:

```
# nested resources:
resources :sports, :only => [:index, :show] do
  resources :competitions, , :only => [:index, :show]
end

# pretty urls:
match "/show/:sport_name/:competition_name" => "competitions#show"
```

You need the "/show" first because otherwise this route will also route every other route (like /sports/new) to `competitions#show`. Of course you can rename this to whatever fits your situation most.

Now you can access the sport via `params[:sport_name]` and the competition via `params[:competition_name]` in `competitions#show`.

If you want rails to generate the paths for you, append some code to the route:

```
match "/show/:sport_name/:competition_name" => "competitions#show", :as => "some_name"
```

and generate the paths like this:

```
some_name_path( "sport", "competition" )
```

This should result in something like "/show/sport/competition".